# using for loop to replace values of keys in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Trying to let the user input a number and replace the value of the key in the dict with an X. Here's an example

```
Size--> 9
key:6
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: X, 7: 7, 8: 8}
```

Here's what i've tried:

```
 dict = {} 
    size=int(input('Size--> '))
    for i in range (size):
        d={i:i}
        dict.update(d)
    for i in range(size):
        testcoor=int(input('key:'))
        if testcoor==i: 
            d1 = {i: 'X'}
            dict.update(d1)
        print(dict)
```

the problem is that the i doesnt seem to represent the loop count, and if an X is replaced it comes with a quotation ' X '. Thx in advance.

Comment: i have to keep looping the input because the hw requires me to keep letting the user input a number and printing out the new dictionary, until values of all the keys become an X

Comment: 'X' is a string, it will always be in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

wait, what exactly are you trying to do? If you simply want to replace a key use this

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```

also why are you taking your input inside the loop (line 7)?
Can you please explain the problem better?

Comment: im trying to change the value of the key (to X), instead of the name of the key.

Comment: okay. you can use the above to replace a key. You can't directly change a key from a dictionary , instead what you do is copy the value of the original key and assign it to the new key, finally delete the old key.
Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {} 
size=int(input('Size--> '))
for i in range (size):
    d={i:i}
    dict.update(d)

testcoor=int(input('key:'))
dict[testcoor] = 'X'
```

What this does is replaces the value of user input key to 'X'. I hope this is what you wanted.

Output from above code:
[image]

The quotations around `X` will always be present as it is a string. The interpreter understands that this is a string because of the quotations, so you cannot remove it.